# Allow blog user to upload image and include it in post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I'm new to php, in over my head and need some help.

Using tutorials I have created a site which has users, some of whom are admin who can create blog posts. The posts are stored in a SQL database. What I have done is created an upload which puts the images in a folder and then displays thumbnails which are linked anchor tags. The blog is stored in Longtext and my plan is to have the blogger to click on one of the thumbnails when their cursor is in the position they wish to embed the image. I think i need to create a reference to the image, include it in the longtext field and then print the image when the blog is displayed. Is this possible?

My html is:

```
<center>
    <form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input placeholder="Title" name="title" type="text" autofocus size="48"><br /><br />
        <textarea placeholder="Content" name="content" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br />
        <input name="post" type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
</center>
<div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">Upload Images</h1>
    <div align="center">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#src_img_upload" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Upload Image</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="image_gallery">
    <?php
        $images = glob("host/*.*");
        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            echo '<a href="" onclick="on_callPhp()" ><img src="'.$image.'" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:200px;max-height:200px"></a>';
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
    <br/>
<div id="src_img_upload" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Multiple Files</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" id="upload_form">
                    <label>Select Multiple Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="img_select" multiple>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created an onclick Javascript to display an alert when I click an image. I think i need to use this to realise the image directory.

```
function on_callPhp()
    {
        var result="<?php php_func();?>";
        alert(result) ;
        return false
    }
<?php function php_func()
{

    echo "Image Clicked";

} ?>
```

My php to store and display the images is:

```
<?php 
 $output = '';  
 if(is_array($_FILES))  
 {  
      foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $name => $value)  
      {  
           $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['images']['name'][$name]);  
           $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");  
           if(in_array($file_name[1], $allowed_extension))  
           {  
                $new_name = rand() . '.'. $file_name[1];  
                $sourcePath = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$name];  
                $targetPath = "path/".$new_name;  
                move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);  
           }  
      }  
      $images = glob("path/*.*");  
      foreach($images as $image)  
      {  
           $output .= '<div class="col-md-2" align="center" ><a href="" onclick="on_callPhp()" ><img src="'.$image.'" width="150px" max-height="150px" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" /></a></div>';  

      }  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

I have cobbled this together from numurous sources and up to now it seems to work OK. I just cannot get over the next hurdle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologise for any blatent oversights/mistakes as I am really new to this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking and I hope you didn't create your own blog platform when there are so many freely available.

Comment: I'm beginning to thing that's exactly what I have done! What i want to do is have a user be able to upload images to their post. I would like them to be able to appear in the text where the user wants them. I know its a roundabout way of having a blog, but I've learned alot up to now and dont want to abandon it. I think that I need is to reference my image in the post and then when I display the post show the image instead of the reference.

Comment: Allowing your users (even if authenticated) to upload files directly to your web server has huge security implications. What if they upload a malicious file? or upload 10 huge image files that could overwhelm and bring down your web server. You will have to use multiple checks and balances to make sure it does not break your website.